# Terraform YAML config - object does not have an attribute names

Tags: terraform, hcl, confluent-cloud

I'm pulling my hair out trying to debug an issue where I have a yaml file which contains two attributes per entry:

```
topics:
  - name: topic_one
    partitions: 24
  - name: topic_two
    partitions: 1
  - name: topic_three
    partitions: 12
  - name: topic_four
    partitions: 6
```

I'm pulling this into TF with:

```
locals {
  confluent = yamldecode(file("./confluent.yaml"))["topics"]

  confluent_topics = flatten([for topic in local.confluent :
  {
    "name"       = topic.name
    "partitions" = topic.partitions
  }])
}
```

Passing into the module with:

```
module "confluent" {
  source = "./modules/confluent-cloud"
  count  = var.confluent_cluster ? 1 : 0
  topics = local.confluent_topics
  
  region = var.region
}
```

Then in the module:

```
resource "confluent_kafka_topic" "kafka" {
  for_each = {
    for topic in var.topics : topic.name => name
  }  

  kafka_cluster {
    id = confluent_kafka_cluster.kafka.id
  }
  topic_name = each.value.name
  partitions_count = each.value.partitions
  ...
```

I've tried just about every combination, and I've set the variable type in the modules `variables.tf` to just about everything imaginable.. but the error is that it doesn't think the object has an attribute named `partitions` - I've tried simplifying the local without flattening the list, I've tried so many different variations.. but always something like this;

```
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on main.tf line 40, in locals:
│   40:     "partitions" = topic.partitions
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "partitions".
```

Console gives me:

```
> local.confluent
[
  {
    "name" = "topic_one"
    "partitions" = 24
  },
  {
    "name" = "topic_two"
    "partitions" = 1
  },
  {
    "name" = "topic_three"
    "partitions" = 12
  },
  {
    "name" = "topic_four"
    "partitions" = 6
  }
```

Console on the flattened local just returns:

```
> local.confluent_topics
(known after apply)
```

...which is somewhat puzzling because I think it should know this without apply, however.. I'm fairly confident this is not my issue.

The annoying thing is I've done this before without issue.. so I'm wondering whether this is a TF Version situation where something has to be handled differently?

```
❯ terraform version
Terraform v1.1.7
on darwin_arm64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/confluentinc/confluent v0.7.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v4.12.1
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/kubernetes v2.11.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/null v3.1.1
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/random v3.1.3
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/tls v3.3.0

Your version of Terraform is out of date! The latest version
is 1.1.9. You can update by downloading from https://www.terraform.io/downloads.html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is all well, except the looping with attribute `name`. You can't have the `name` attribute & fetch the `partitions` field from it. It can be only fetched from `topic` object.

Try this..

```
resource "confluent_kafka_topic" "kafka" {
  for_each = {
    for topic in var.topics : topic.name => topic
  }  

  kafka_cluster {
    id = confluent_kafka_cluster.kafka.id
  }
  topic_name = each.value.name
  partitions_count = each.value.partitions
  ...
```

You have the unique key in the form of `topic.name` & `topic` is the object which has `partitions` field.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'm not entirely sure I follow what you mean here. In this part aren't we just telling the loop to treat `name` as the key for the loop. Thus, run the loop for every unique name you find? Admittedly, my in depth knowledge of this particular function is lacking.

Comment: That said, I get the same error when changing it as you suggested :(

Comment: Did you change your `for_each` from `for_each = {
    for topic in var.topics : topic.name => name
  }` to `for_each = {
    for topic in var.topics : topic.name => topic
  }`.. You still get the same error?

Comment: For me `terraform validate` & `terraform plan` worked. Can you post your updated code?

Comment: `for_each = { for topic in var.topics : topic.name => topic }` I get the same error from `terraform validate` : `This object does not have an attribute named "partitions".`

Comment: Do you have special characters wrt., `partitions` field? As you are reading from the file? It worked for me

Comment: I put a dump of the yaml in the original question.. the partitions field is an int as opposed to string. I've tried to address that in the variable declaration, but I don't think that should really matter hugely?

Comment: I can see so many examples online which suggest I've been doing it correctly. This is so confusing to me.

Comment: I appear to be doing the same as these articles: https://medium.com/@dfinnoy/understandable-terraform-projects-9c1cd9b4b21a & https://aws.plainenglish.io/terraform-yaml-%EF%B8%8F-3550a3642dd3

Comment: Why not? You should be using `int` as `confluent_kafka_topic` resource expects that type. Nevertheless, in that case you would get validation error from the provider rather the one you got. I still hunch something wrong at your end as `plan` worked at my end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244642/discussion-between-jonnybinthemix-and-harshavmb).

Answer (score 0):

I think another part of your problem is that you are trying to flatten your topics that are already flattened and can be accessed. Your local.confluent and local.confluent_topics result in the same object.

You should change your TF module resource to access the local.confluent instead of creating another flattened local object that is exactly the same.

Also, like the answer above said, you need to change your resource for_each to:

```
for_each = { for topic in var.topics : topic.name => topic }
```

Or, put another way,

```
for_each = { for key in var.topics : key.name => key (this is your new key) }
```

I would also suggest using output variables to make your object troubleshooting easier.

If you have multiple YAML files you actually need to do another iteration in your for loop in local.confluent_topics, and you need to iterate over the values.

Your flatten code for multiple YAML files with topics would look like this.

```
confluent_topics = flatten([
for k, v in local.confluents : [
  for topic in v : {
    name       = topic.name
    partitions = topic.partitions
  }
]])
```

This will make your local.flatten_topics look like you expect.

```
confluent_topics = [
   {
      name       = "topic1"
      partitions = 24
    },
]
```